# drawing page header/footer with javascript includes and document.write

Tags: javascript, html

Our  sprawling corporate site uses javascript to draw a header/footer on every page using document.write. This allows us to very easily maintain the "skin" of our site from one place. This approach has served us well for several years.

Recently, however, we're running in to major difficulty with IE. The problem seems to stem from the fact that the header javascript opens a tag which is closed by the footer script. The header and footer are used to "wrap" the body in a series of divs which give the proper skin.

At the same time, we have lots of fancy dom manipulation happening in the body of the page. IE is now complaining loudly and often about the fact that we're trying to modify dom elements before they've been closed, like this:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Timestamp: Tue, 3 Jan 2012 22:20:28 UTC

```
Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://dev.site.com/business_portal_test.jsp
```

Some questions:

- Is using javascript includes to "wrap" core content in additional divs reasonable approach?
- Can anyone point to any high-quality, high traffic sites which use this technique?
- Does this technique have a name?

Comment: Reasonable, but all your structural and wrapper divs should be built server-side, then your js can safely skin the completed pages.

Comment: Thanks Mouse Food. Updated the question to reflect that this js is creating additional structural/wrapper divs.

Comment: "Does this technique have a name?"  Possibly, "Obsolete" :-)  You can achieve the same effect by having a script run from the end of the page that *wraps* appropriate page elements in the additional header/footer stuff you require.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Please keep these comments coming and help me make a case for tearing out the offending code and doing it right!

Comment: Also, that's great suggestion. I hadn't considered that we might be able to wrap the content by using just a single script.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with this approach is that it makes the entire layout of your site depended on javascript, something which goes completely against accepted best practices.  You could easily achieve the same level of maintainability using includes on the server side or the concept of master pages. Unless there is a very specific reason to do so JS shouldn't really be used for the layout, or skinning of your site.